# Using ffmpeg with MTS files created from Canon video camera

Tags: ffmpeg, video, mts

I have a HF G30 canon camcorder which produces MTS files that mediainfo says are BDAV files.

I film events and might have 2 hours of footage for 10 minutes of action, so want to chop them down before saving and importing into premiere pro.

I have not found any decent software to do this, so tried to use ffmpeg on command line, however after something like

`.\ffmpeg.exe -i .\00000.MTS -ss 1:26:09 -t 0:0:5 -vcodec copy -acodec copy outputvideo.MTS`

I am getting a large set of errors that read

`[vost#0:0/copy @ 00000209d223e9c0] cur_dts is invalid [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)`

I have spent the last few hours looking online, however have found nothing helpful, which is unusual!

Any advice?

Comment: Not sure what you googled. Try "HF G30 canon mts file" for example

Comment: Googling that has this post as the top result.  However it doesn't yield any results relating to ffmpeg and as that's not in your search terms, that doesn't surprise me.